# Use of undefined constant APPLICATION_ENV

Tags: php, zend-framework

A friend asked me to migrate his site developed with Zend Framework to another server. I copied all the files and imported the database locally, in testing, the following messages are displayed in the browser:

> Notice: Use of undefined constant APPLICATION_ENV - assumed 'APPLICATION_ENV' in C: \ wamp \ www \ zend \ new \ public_html \ index.php on line 5
>
> Warning: require_once (Zend / Application.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C: \ wamp \ www \ zend \ new \ public_html \ index.php on line 10
>
> Fatal error: require_once (): Failed opening required 'Zend / Application.php' (include_path = 'C: \ php. \ Pear') in C: \ wamp \ www \ zend \ new \ public_html \ index.php on line 10

The code seems very confusing, I cannot find the problem being that nothing has changed.

I do not know Zend, and need a hand.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using zf1 in your public/index.php put this:

```
// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
|| define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'development'));
```

or you can also edit your virtual host configuration adding this line:

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
```

Comment: There's an extra ` (backtick) in your answer... (after the closing double-quotes).

Answer (score 1):

As documented in http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.application.quick-start.html:

> You may note that the application environment constant value looks for
>   an environment variable "APPLICATION_ENV". We recommend setting this
>   in your web server environment. In Apache, you can set this either in
>   your vhost definition, or in your .htaccess file. We recommend the
>   following contents for your public/.htaccess file:

I'd suggest looking at the vhost/apache/nginx/etc config for the old server and looking for something like `SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV`.